# Multiple swf files not loading in DNN 5.X

Tags: firefox, swfobject, dotnetnuke

We have run numerous tests now and it has now come down to either a DNN-SWFObject loading multiple swf files on a page or Firefox bug.

Here's the outcome we need:

Two swf files on one page:

1. Header.swf: which holds the nav and some bling animation.
2. Map.swf: which has different provinces of the country highlighted on rollover. The active province is highlighted by reading the URL via Javascript and then loaded into the Map.swf via FlashVars.

In all of our other tests in other browsers, the scenario works very well but in Firefox 3.5.3 The swf files refuse to show.

We have stripped this test down to the bare minimum, one html page scenario and embedding it the same way using SWFObject 2.2 and this works in Firefox. When it is uploaded in DNN, the swf files refuse to show.

Is there anything anyone can think of?

Many thanks,
James

Answer (score 0):

My first thought would be the way dnn renames element ids - and are you using client ids

If you could post some code it might help to look at it or a url to look at